# What are these holes in my Connect Wall?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, cryptic-clues, connect-wall

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7045/fortnightly-topic-challenge-42-wordless-connecting-walls)</sup>

---

"Why on earth are there blank spaces in your connect wall?"

"In my defense, you just asked me to make categories with four words in them; you never said *how many* categories."

"It's a 4x4 grid! How many categories do you *think*? Ugh, I need to get this published in five minutes!"

"That sounds like a 'you' problem to me."

"Are you kidding? It's your fault!"

"Hey, I delivered what you asked for, didn't I? I even went through the trouble of making cryptic clues! All right, here's an idea: publish it anyway, and call it the 'Hole in the Wall.' Just pretend the holes are intentional, you know, for the pun."

"That's the stupidest idea I've ever heard! And what if someone asks **what kind of holes these are?**"

"That's...a good question."

[image]

---

**Notes**:

- The final answer is a four-letter word that answers the question, "What kind of holes are these?"
- This puzzle assumes familiarity with the [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall) genre.
- In case you have trouble viewing the image, [here's](https://pastebin.com/raw/yqVFwNmM) the transcription.

Comment: Well, they're in your post, so they must be [postholes](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/posthole)!

Comment: @msh210 can't argue with that :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that the solutions to the cryptic clues are as follows...

> *A vessel with no obtuse ends!* = **CANOE** = CAN + (n)O + (obtus)E &lit!
>
>  *To give the greatest expression of pain* = **BESTOW** = BEST + OW
>
>  *This man, one who provides citations in the wrong way (a liar, primarily) is against common beliefs* = **HERETICAL** = HE + CITER< + A + L(iar)
>
>  *Mad genius eats ball of fire* = **IGNEOUS** = GENIUS* around O ('ball')
>
>  *Mark, in good shape, goes back, gets a drug* = **DENOTE** = TONED< + E ('drug') *(solved by @jafe in comments)*
>
>  *Gasp! That guy, placed at the top of the hall of fame?* = **PANTHEON** = PANT + HE + ON *(solved by @jafe in comments)*
>
>  *Got there roughly at the same time* = **TOGETHER** = GOTTHERE*
>
>  *Blazing row that shows escalation* = **GROWTH** = _G ROW TH_*
>
>  *Dry, dishevelled owlet* = **TOWEL** = OWLET*
>
>  *Reflection of a lake captured in fine instrument* = **THEREMIN** = MERE< in THIN
>
>  *Modern unit of weight* = **NEWTON** = NEW + TON &lit!
>
>  *The beer talks random nonsense* = **BLETHERSKATE** = THEBEERTALKS*

...we next notice that these answers can be split into three groups...

> ...depending on whether they contain **a run of letters which is an anagram of the numbers ONE, TWO or THREE**:
>
>  ONE: CA**NOE**, IG**NEO**US, D**ENO**TE, PANTH**EON**;
>  TWO: BES**TOW**, NE**WTO**N, GR**OWT**H, **TOW**EL;
>  THREE: **THERE**MIN, TOG**ETHER**, BL**ETHER**SKATE, **HERET**ICAL.

Next, we should notice the numbers in the corner of each box that contains a clue:

> If we treat these as indices and look up the letter in that position within the word, we can read '**A SLITHERLINK**'. This implies to me that we now need to solve *a* [slitherlink](/questions/tagged/slitherlink) *grid-deduction puzzle* based on whether each answer contains a 1, 2 or 3.
>
>  Our initial slitherlink grid and its final resolved state then look like this:
>
>  [image]
>
>  And superimposing this on the original connecting wall yields this:
>
>  [image]

Finally, as pointed out by @HTM in comments (nice spot), let's focus on the cells containing the 'holes', and specifically...

> ...the shape of the loop that passes around their cell borders:
>
>  [image]
>
>  We have here an implementation of the **[pigpen cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher)**! If we order the cells by their Roman numerals (and include the cells' central dots) we see this sequence:
>
>  [image]
>
>  This is the pigpen encoding for **LOOP**, which means that these holes are **LOOPHOLES**! What an incredibly apt name for them, considering they are formed by the slitherlink *loop*. Great puzzle!

Comment: Last one's rot13(qrabg<+r), i think?

Comment: @jafe AH, nice! I was sure that 'drug' was the definition part... Will add with credit, thanks.

Comment: The cryptics and categories are all correct, as is jafe's answer. :) The final answer is not quite it, I'm afraid; there are a few more steps involved. (In retrospect, the next necessary mental leap might not be as natural as I thought; I'll add a hint if no one gets it after a while.)

Comment: @Ankoganit Aha, okay - well consider this a couple of steps in the right direction then! :) My suspicion was that we might be required to do something rot13(hfvat gur yrsgbire yrggref bapr gur ahzoref ner erzbirq), but the second group in particular led to an awful lot of consonants!

Comment: (oh also, the intended wordplay for the first one was "...+_B+_R")

Comment: Note from the question that "The final answer is a four-letter word" (hopefully in the literal sense, not the idiomatic one).

Comment: (from chat) I realized the puzzle is a bit under-clued, so I thought of a way to modify the puzzle to fix that. Trouble is, that invalidates about 15% (maybe less, even) of the progress you have already made. Would you be okay with this edit? Alternatively, I can just keep it as is and add a hint.

Comment: @Ankoganit No worries - happy to modify my answer once the edit is in :)

Comment: I think the gasp one is rot13(cnag+ur+ba)

Comment: @jafe That looks bang on! Great spot again, thanks :)

Comment: To save you some trouble, ANSI/Morse code isn't involved. (Although [tag:cipher] *is* one of the tags...)

Comment: @Ankoganit Seriously, that was just a coincidence?! Crazy...!

Comment: (I'm surprised too)

Comment: I believe the cipher is the rot13(cvtcra pvcure. Vs jr hfr gur Fyvgureyvax fbyhgvba rqtrf gbtrgure jvgu gur qbgf va gur rzcgl pryyf, jr trg gur jbeq YBBC, juvpu vf gur nafjre gb gur dhrfgvba - gurl ner “ybbcubyrf.”)

Comment: @HTM You got it!

Comment: @HTM Oh, well done! I even tried that cipher, but using the four quarters of the grid rather than the loop itself. Shaking my head that I didn't spot that. Makes for a perfectly fitting solution - very nice :) Will edit that in shortly for a complete solution, with credit - very nice spot!